# Googlemaps API in Internet Explorer

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3

Recently a Googlemap API that i have created has stopped working in INternet Explorer (version 9 but also tried previous versions as well), yet still works in Chrome and I dont understand why.

If anybody could shed some light on this I would be grateful.

Many Thanks

The code is as follows:

```
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 900px; height: 750px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
        var locations = [
        ['<h4><b>Kings Hill Office Area 4</></h4> <br>Balfour Beatty Mott MacDonald Area 4,10 Kings Hill Avenue, Kings Hill, Kent. ME19 4AR<br>Depot Champion:  <br>Depot Contact <br>More Text Here <br><a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?ll=51.275508,0.396321&z=17&daddr=Balfour+Beatty,+10+Kings+Hill+Ave,+Kings+Hill,+West+Malling,+Kent+ME19+4AR&output=classic&dg=ntvb"target="_blank"/>Click Here to get Directions to this location',51.275286, 0.395393],
    ['<h4><b>Spencer House Office Area 10</></h4> <br>Spencer House, 35 Dewhurst Road Birchwood. WA3<br>Depot Champion:  <br>Depot Contact <br>More Text Here <br><a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?ll=53.4118618,-2.5195415&z=15&daddr=53.4141389,-2.5269444&output=classic&dg=ntvb" target="_blank"/>Click Here to get Directions to this location', 53.414139, -2.526935], 
    ['<h4><b>Highways Agency Regional Office</></h4> <br>Floor 3B, Federated House, London Road, Dorking.RH4 1SZ<br>Depot Champion:  <br>Depot Contact <br>More Text Here <br><a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?ll=51.2381366,-0.3245188&z=17&daddr=Highways+Agency,+Federated+House/London+Rd,+Dorking+RH4+1SZ&output=classic&dg=ntvb" target="_blank"/>Click Here to get Directions to this location', 51.239054, -0.324669],
        ['<h4><b>BB Workplace Basingstoke</></h4> <br>Central Office, Pavillion B, Ashwood Park, Ashwood Way, Basingstoke.Hants. RG23 8BG<br>Depot Champion:  <br>Depot Contact <br>More Text Here <br><a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?ll=51.274606,-1.113179&z=19&daddr=Balfour+Beatty+Ltd,+Pavilion,+C2+Ashwood+Park,+Basingstoke,+Hampshire+RG23+8BG&output=classic&dg=ntvb" target="_blank"/>Click Here to get Directions to this location', 51.274646,-1.113198],
    ['<h4><b>Mott MacDonald, Stoneham</></h4> <br>Stoneham Place, Stoneham Lane, Southampton.Hants. SO50 9NW<br>Depot Champion:  <br>Depot Contact <br>More Text Here <br><a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?ll=50.95431,-1.372636&z=17&daddr=Mott+MacDonald,+Stoneham+Place,+Stoneham+Ln,+Southampton,+Hampshire+SO50+9NW&output=classic&dg=ntvb" target="_blank"/>Click Here to get Directions to this location', 50.954319,-1.372759],
    ['<h4><b>Mott MacDonald Croydon</></h4> <br>Mott MacDonald House, 8-10 Sydenham Road, Croydon, Surrey. CR0 2EE<br>Depot Champion:  <br>Depot Contact <br>More Text Here <br><a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?ll=51.378,-0.096918&z=17&daddr=Mott+MacDonald,+8-10+Sydenham+Road,+Croydon+CR0+2EE&output=classic&dg=ntvb" target="_blank"/>Click Here to get Directions to this location', 51.377943,-0.096613],
    ['<h4><b>Farthing Corner Depot</></h4><br>M2 Farthing Corner Depot, Gillingham, ME8 8PG<br>Depot Champion:  <br>Depot Contact <br>More Text Here <br><a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?ll=51.3411297,0.6074175&z=17&daddr=M2,+Rainham,+Gillingham,+Medway+ME8&output=classic&dg=ntvb" target="_blank"/>Click Here to get Directions to this location', 51.340259, 0.605905],  
    ['<h4><b>Coldharbour Depot</></h4> <br>M20 Coldharbour Depot, Coldharbour Lane, Little Preston, Aylesford. ME20 7NS<br>Depot Champion:  <br>Depot Contact <br>More Text Here <br><a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?ll=51.2975005,0.485606&z=15&daddr=51.297501,0.485606&output=classic&dg=ntvb"target="_blank"/>Click Here to get Directions to this location', 51.297501, 0.485606],
    ['<h4><b>Stanford Depot</></h4> <br>M20 Stanford Depot, Honeywood, Sandling, Hythe. Kent. CT21 4UX<br>Depot Champion:  <br>Depot Contact <br>More Text Here <br><a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?ll=51.0933623,1.0526985&z=17&daddr=51.0938,1.0518&output=classic&dg=ntvb"target="_blank"/>Click Here to get Directions to this location', 51.093800,1.051800],
    ['<h4><b>WeatherHill Depot</></h4> <br>M23 Weatherhill Depot, Hathersham Close, Smallfield.Surrey. RH6 9JE<br>Depot Champion:  <br>Depot Contact <br>More Text Here <br><a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?ll=51.1772075,-0.1255377&z=16&daddr=51.177699,-0.125999&output=classic&dg=ntvb"target="_blank"/>Click Here to get Directions to this location', 51.177699, -0.125999],
    ['<h4><b>Ford Depot</></h4> <br>A27 Ford Depot, Ford Lane, Ford, Near Arundel, BN18 0DF<br>Depot Champion:  <br>Depot Contact <br>More Text Here <br><a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?ll=50.8254764,-0.591252&z=15&daddr=50.825477,-0.591252&output=classic&dg=ntvb" target="_blank"/>Click Here to get Directions to this location',50.825477, -0.591252],
    ['<h4><b>Lewes Depot</></h4> <br>Broyle Place Farm, Laughton Road, Ringmer. BN8 5SD<br>Depot Champion:  <br>Depot Contact <br>More Text Here <br><a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?ll=50.8963954,0.10098&z=15&daddr=50.896396,0.10098&output=classic&dg=ntvb" target="_blank"/>Click Here to get Directions to this location', 50.896396,0.100980],
    ['<h4><b>Westhoughton Depot</></h4><br>Dehavilland Way, Westhoughton, Bolton. BL5 3NH<br>Depot Champion:  <br>Depot Contact <br>More Text Here <br><a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?ll=53.4118618,-2.5195415&z=15&daddr=53.4141389,-2.5269444&output=classic&dg=ntvb" target="_blank"/>Click Here to get Directions to this location', 53.573025, -2.552319],
    ['<h4><b>Preston Brook Depot</><h4><br>A56 Chester Road, Preston Brook, Runcorn. WA7 3BA<br>Depot Champion:  <br>Depot Contact <br>More Text Here <br><a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?ll=53.4118618,-2.5195415&z=15&daddr=53.4141389,-2.5269444&output=classic&dg=ntvb" target="_blank"/>Click Here to get Directions to this location', 53.313110, -2.674027],
          ['<h4><b>Hale Depot</></h4><br>Wilmslow Road Roundabout, Hale, Altrincham. WA15 8XL<br><br>Depot Champion:  <br>Depot Contact <br>More Text Here <br><a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?ll=53.3505295,-2.2909&z=15&daddr=53.35053,-2.2909&output=classic&dg=ntvb" target="_blank"/>Click Here to get Directions to this location', 53.350530, -2.290900],
          ['<h4><b>Brinnington Depot</></h4> <br>Ashton Road Roundabout, Bredbury, Stockport. SK6 2QN<br>Depot Champion:  <br>Depot Contact <br>More Text Here <br><a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?ll=53.3505295,-2.2909&z=15&daddr=53.35053,-2.2909&output=classic&dg=ntvb" target="_blank"/>Click Here to get Directions to this location', 53.426265, -2.121903],
      ['<h4><b>Milnrow Depot</></h4><br>Elizabeth Way, Milnrow, Rochdale. OL16 4NH<br>Depot Champion:  <br>Depot Contact <br>More Text Here <br><a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?ll=53.6101112,-2.1163191&z=17&daddr=53.610498,-2.114581&output=classic&dg=ntvb" target="_blank"/>Click Here to get Directions to this location', 53.610498, -2.114581],
          ['<h4><b>Knutsford Depot</></h4><br>Northwich Way, Tabley, Knutsford. WA16 0TL<br>Depot Champion:  <br>Depot Contact <br>More Text Here <br><a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?ll=53.3026095,-2.400456&z=15&daddr=53.30261,-2.400456&output=classic&dg=ntvb" target="_blank"/>Click Here to get Directions to this location', 53.302610, -2.400456],
          ['<h4><b>Charnock Richard Depot</></h4><br>Mill Lane, Charnock Richard, Chorley.<br>Depot Champion:  <br>Depot Contact <br>More Text Here <br><a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?ll=53.6292425,-2.685604&z=15&daddr=53.629243,-2.685604&output=classic&dg=ntvb" target="_blank"/>Click Here to get Directions to this location', 53.629243, -2.685604],
          ['<h4><b>Newton Le Willows Depot</></h4><br>Rob Lane, Newton Le Willows, Warrington. WA12 0DR<br>Depot Champion:  <br>Depot Contact <br>More Text Here <br><a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?ll=53.4596006,-2.6166221&z=17&daddr=53.460224,-2.616783&output=classic&dg=ntvb" target="_blank"/>Click Here to get Directions to this location', 53.460224, -2.616783],
      ['<h4><b>Whitebirk Depot</></h4><br>Whitebank Bleachworks, Whitebank Road, Blackburn. BB1 3HY<br>Depot Champion:  <br>Depot Contact <br>More Text Here <br><a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?ll=53.7518802,-2.4479139&z=16&daddr=53.751481,-2.445178&output=classic&dg=ntvb" target="_blank"/>Click Here to get Directions to this location', 53.751481, -2.445178],
      ['<h4><b>Tarbock Depot</></h4><br>Huyton, Prescott. Merseyside. L35 1QY<br>Depot Champion:  <br>Depot Contact <br>More Text Here <br><a href="https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?ll=53.3982515,-2.818008&z=15&daddr=53.398252,-2.818008&output=classic&dg=ntvb" target="_blank"/>Click Here to get Directions to this location', 53.398252, -2.818008]
        ];

    // Setup the different icons and shadows
    var iconURLPrefix = 'http://<location of images>/';

    var icons = [
      iconURLPrefix + 'rangerstation.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'rangerstation.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'truck.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'ltblu-pushpin.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'ylw-pushpin.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'blue-pushpin.png',      
      iconURLPrefix + 'FarthingCorner_Icon.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'ColdHarbour_Icon.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'Stanford_Icon.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'WeatherHill_Icon.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'Ford_Icon.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'Lewes_Icon.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'WestHoughton_Icon.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'Preston_Brook_Icon.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'Hale_Icon.png',
iconURLPrefix + 'Brinnington_Icon.png',
iconURLPrefix + 'Milnrow_Icon.png',
iconURLPrefix + 'Knutsford_Icon.png',
iconURLPrefix + 'Charnock_Richard_Icon.png',
iconURLPrefix + 'Newton_Le_Willows_Icon.png',
iconURLPrefix + 'WhiteBirk_Icon.png',
iconURLPrefix + 'Tarbock_Depot.png',

    ]
    var icons_length = icons.length;

    var shadow = {
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(15,33),
      url: iconURLPrefix + 'msmarker.shadow.png'
    };


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.520661, -86.802490),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      panControl: false,
    scrollwheel: false, 
      zoomControlOptions: {
         position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
      }
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      maxWidth: 160
    });

    var marker;
    var markers = new Array();

    var iconCounter = 0;

    // Add the markers and infowindows to the map
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon : icons[iconCounter],
        shadow: shadow
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));

      iconCounter++;
      // We only have a limited number of possible icon colors, so we may have to restart the counter
      if(iconCounter >= icons_length){
        iconCounter = 0;
      }
    }

    function AutoCenter() {
      //  Create a new viewpoint bound
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      //  Go through each...
      $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
        bounds.extend(marker.position);
      });
      //  Fit these bounds to the map
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
    AutoCenter();



  </script>
```

---

Comment: Does it work in more modern versions of IE?  What errors do you get in IE9?

Comment: everything up to ie9 doesnt work. I am not currently working with IE10 in the business.

Comment: The IE Developer console has the following error:

Comment: SCRIPT1015: Unterminated string constant 
%7Bcommon,map,util,marker%7D.js, line 4 character 22202

Comment: Perhaps try the frozen (v=3.0) or release (v=3) versions of the API, currently you are currently using the experimental version (v=3.exp if you don't specify a version), it is possible that doesn't work with IE9.

Answer (score 0):

You have "hanging commas" (a comma after the last data element of an array or object), that causes older versions of IE to add an extraneous null element/property, which caused the Google Maps Javascript API to fail.  Remove them.

```
iconURLPrefix + 'WhiteBirk_Icon.png',
iconURLPrefix + 'Tarbock_Depot.png',

]
```

Comment: See, that was my initial thought but having removed the last commas it still doesnt show in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks geocodezip, your advise put me on track to resolve. I added an API key and that seems to have fixed it for me.

Thanks everyone for their assistance much appreciated.